# How to define class with self-referencing generics constraint in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics

As shown in this [article](http://dvanderboom.wordpress.com/2008/03/15/treet-implementing-a-non-binary-tree-in-c/), one can define in C#:

```
public class MyTreeNode<T> where T: MyTreeNode<T>
{

}
```

In Delphi, however, the following code does not compile and complains "E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'MyTreeNode<>'":

```
type
    TMyTreeNode<T: TMyTreeNode<T>> = class
    end;
```

The formal terminology seems to be ["self-referencing generics constraint"](http://rtb.rousso.eu/2013/06/self-referencing-generic-type-constraint.html). I wonder how to do this in Delphi ?

PS:

[Another useful article as David pointed out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx).

[Relevent SO post regarding Delphi and covariance / contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404734/).

[Wikipedia page of co/contra-variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: You just cannot do that with Delphi generic constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way in Delphi to express such a generic constraint. Furthermore, I believe that there is no typesafe way to achieve what can be achieved in C# with such a constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! Could you help to explain more about "there is no typesafe way to achieve what can be achieved in C# with such a constraint" ?

Comment: You are using generics because you want type safety. You can implement the container without type safety by abandoning generics.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! Could you help to show an example regarding "You can implement the container without type safety by abandoning generics." ?

Comment: I suppose that you simply remove the constraint and instead add runtime type checking whenever an element is added to the container.